# Method Not Allowed. Flask receives GET instead of POST

Tags: python, post, flask

I'm trying to get used to the Flask API and I'm creating a simple page with 1 form which uses POST method.

Instead when I look at the Flask output I can see that any time I try to open the /configure view Flask receives a GET method instead and returns Method not allowed on the view.

test.py -

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
    abort, render_template, flash
import dude

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    output = None
    if retval:
        output = "True"
    elif retval == False:
        output = "False" + error
    return render_template('index.html', output=output)

@app.route('/configure', methods=['POST'])
def configure():
    hostname = request.form['hostname']
    if hostname in ip_dict:
        _info.append(hostname)
        flash('good job')
    else:
        flash('Host name not in the DNS system')
    return render_template('configure.html')

if __name__== "__main__":
    WB = dude.Dude()
    retval, error, ip_dict = WB.get_ips()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>configurator</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<div class=page>
    <h1>Configurator</h1>
    <div class=metanav>
        <p>{{ output }}</p>
        <a href="{{ url_for('configure') }}">Configure</a>
    </div>
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
        <div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

configure.html

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>Configure</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('configure') }}" method=post class=hostname>
    <d1>
        <dt>Host name:
        <dd><input type=text name=hostname size=15>
        <dd><input type=submit value=Submit>
    </d1>
    </form>
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
        <div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and the console output from Flask

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2016 19:24:25] "GET /configure HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

UPDATE

I found my mistake. I am rendering template index.html in a place where I should be instead rendering configure.html. After this in configure() I am rendering a template where instead I should redirect.

This is how the new methods look like.

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    output = None
    if retval:
        output = "True"
    elif retval == False:
        output = "False" + error
    return render_template('configure.html', output=output)

@app.route('/comeon', methods=['POST'])
def configure():
    hostname = request.form['hostname']
    if hostname in ip_dict:
        _info.append(hostname)
        flash('good job')
    else:
        flash('Host name not in the DNS system')
    return redirect(url_for('hello'))
```

Comment: You could start with fixing your HTML. There have to be quotation marks around attribute values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however this wasn't a solution to my problem.

Comment: @KlausD. That's just flat out not true.

Answer (score 3):

Then you are trying to open `/configure` in browser it by defaults uses `GET` method.
Since you've specified only `POST` for that url you are getting error.

And you have some problems with your forms.

```
render_template('configure.html')
```

You should pass some arguments such as `hostname` since you are trying to use it in template `<dd><input type=text name=hostname size=15>`.

And this is incorrect syntax. It should be instead:

```
<dd><input type=text name={{ hostname }} size=15>
```

And so on.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately I'm not trying to pass the variable from Python to template.
I'm trying to write a host name in the input form, pass it to python and evaluate if the host name is in the DNS.
Anyways I tried to apply the changes that you suggested, but the error doesn't change.

Comment: @VictorDaskalov (s)he is saying that you will not be able to open the '/configure' view in the browser. You will only be able to POST to it (i.e using the form on your home page.) If you want to be able to navigate to the '/configure' page, add 'GET' to `methods`.